# Mapping HttpClient GET response to an array of objects of a certain type

Tags: angular, typescript

I've created a model for data I'm querying via GET and I'm simply trying to map the output from the GET to an array of this model (a `Player` object).

Here's what the returned response data coming from the API looks like:

```
[
    {
        Id: 1
        PlayerName: "Dave",
        FirstSeason: 2013,
        LastSeason: 2016,
        BattingAverageRecord: [340, 210, 220, 300]
    },
    {
        Id: 2
        PlayerName: "Dennis",
        FirstSeason: 2013,
        LastSeason: 2016,
        BattingAverageRecord: [230, 221, 312, 240]
    },
    {
        Id: 3
        PlayerName: "Mary",
        FirstSeason: 2010,
        LastSeason: 2013,
        BattingAverageRecord: [330, 123, 151, 307]
    }

];
```

I've created a model for the data:

```
export class Player {
    constructor(public Id: number,
                public PlayerName: string, 
                public FirstSeason: number, 
                public LastSeason: number, 
                public BattingAverageRecord: number[]) 
    {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.PlayerName = PlayerName;
        this.FirstSeason = FirstSeason;
        this.LastSeason = LastSeason;
        this.BattingAverageRecord = BattingAverageRecord;
    } 
}
```

Now I'm trying to map response date to an array of `Players`:

```
retrievePlayer(): Observable<any> {

    return this.http.get<Player[]>(this.playerAPI)
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
                return new Player(data.Id, data.PlayerName, data.FirstSeason, data.LastSeason, data.GPARecord))
            }
        )
}
```

What I've tried is obviously wrong.. I've tried doing `new Array(new Player(data.id ...))` but I know that's wrong too.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Try:

data.map(p => new Player(p.Id, ...));

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I knew it would be something simple. If you answer I can mark it as correct. Question, why exactly do we need to map it twice--once at the beginning of the pipe and then again within the first map().

Comment: If you make player an interface you don’t need to instantiate or use map operator, you can just use the type on front of get as you do. Ask yourself if you really need a class. This exact example exists in the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-a-typed-response

Answer (score 0):

when you map you can easily structure your data and return the new structure eg

```
retrievePlayer(): Observable<<Player[]> {

    return this.http.get(this.playerAPI)
        .pipe(
            map(data => {
               return {
                 Id: data.Id,
                 PlayerName: data.PlayerName,
                 FirstSeason: data.FirstSeason,
                 LastSeason: data.LastSeason,
                 BattingAverageRecord: data.GPARecord

               }
            }
        )
    }
```